# mysql create function syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fn_get_entity_by_username;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE function fn_get_entity_by_username
(
    in in_username     varchar,
    out my_entity       integer
)
RETURNS integer DETERMINISTIC
language SQL
BEGIN
    declare my_entity integer(11);
    select entity
      into my_entity
      from tb_entity
     where username = in_username;

END $$
```

I keep having syntax error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'in in_username     varchar,
>       out my_entity       integer ) RETURNS integer DE' at line 3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mixing [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function.html) and [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) syntaxes.

If you meant it to be a function not a procedure there are several problems:

1. You should use `DROP FUNCTION` instead of `DROP PROCEDURE`
2. MySQL function support only `IN` parameters
3. You should use `RETURN` clause to return a result of the function
4. There is no need in a local variable `my_entity` *(BTW if you want for some reason use it in a procedure then you should change its name to disambiguate whether you refer to an OUT parameter or that local variable)*. You can directly `RETURN` the value.

That being said your code might look like this

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_get_entity_by_username;
CREATE FUNCTION fn_get_entity_by_username
(
    in_username VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS INT 
RETURN (SELECT entity
         FROM tb_entity
        WHERE username = in_username);
```

**Note:** since it's a one statement function there is no need to change `DELIMITER` and use `BEGIN...END` block

Sample usage:

```
SELECT fn_get_entity_by_username('user2') my_entity;
```

Sample output:

```
| MY_ENTITY |
|-----------|
|         1 |
```

---

If on the other hand you meant it to be a stored procedure then your code might look like this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_get_entity_by_username;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_entity_by_username
(
    IN  in_username VARCHAR(255),
    OUT my_entity   INT
)
  SET my_entity = (SELECT entity
                     FROM tb_entity
                    WHERE username = in_username);
```

Sample usage:

```
CALL sp_get_entity_by_username('user1', @my_entity);
SELECT @my_entity my_entity;
```

Sample output:

```
| MY_ENTITY |
|-----------|
|         1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58af7/2)** demo (*both for a function and a procedure*)

---

Based on your comments code with `BEGIN...END` block for a function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_get_entity_by_username;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_get_entity_by_username
(
    in_username VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS INT 
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT entity
            FROM tb_entity
           WHERE username = in_username);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For a procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_get_entity_by_username;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_entity_by_username
(
    IN  in_username     VARCHAR(255),
    OUT my_entity       INT
)
BEGIN
  SET my_entity = (SELECT entity
                     FROM tb_entity
                    WHERE username = in_username);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Because I don't want to change my code format, is there anyway to change my code with begin and end statement?.

Comment: Of course you can. Just add `BEGIN...END`. See updated answer.